# How to integrate AWS WAF Intelligent threat API in my Angular app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, captcha, amazon-waf

I am trying to use AWS Waf ClientSide integration with Intelligent Threat API as a form of silent captcha in my Angular client app.

I read AWS Documentation about this but I want to ask if someone has already implemented this in their Angular/React application to have as an example that I can refer to.

Thanks